# How to set type of data with useAsyncData()?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I need to map the data received by useAsyncData, but I can't use `.map()` since the type of `report` is `unknown`. How to set it as `Array` in the code below?

```
interface AsyncDataResult {
  data: []
  pending: boolean
  error: Error | null
}

const {
  data: report,
  pending,
  error,
} = useAsyncData<AsyncDataResult>('report', () =>
  $fetch(
    `https://${
       url[route.params.server]
       }/tb3?s=${
       route.params.survey
       }&k=${
       route.params.password}`,
    {
      method: 'get',
    },
  ),
)

const foo = report?.map((item) => { item.entity })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the `useAsyncData` with your desired type:

```
useAsyncData<MyType[]>(...)
```

Comment: I tried it as you can see in my edit, but I still get the message `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Ref<AsyncDataResult | null>'`

Comment: The type needs to be the return type of your fetch, not the return type of `useAsyncData`.
If you look at my example, the type I pass is an array, not an object.

Comment: Ok, but there's still something I don't get... I replaced `useAsyncData` by `useAsyncData<[]>` but I'm not getting the message: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Ref<[] | null>'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Because you need to access the value of the data:
`const foo = report.value?.map((item) => { item.entity })`